# How to get to array with the smallest sum

Tags: algorithm

I was given this interview question, and I totally blanked out. How would you guys solve this:

Go from the start of an array to the end in a way that you minimize the sum of elements that you land on.

1. You can move to the next element, i.e go from index 1 to index 2.
2. Or you can hop one element over. i.e go from index 1 to index 3.

Comment: Hi, I think this could be better suited for: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com 
Also, just do array[array.lenght-1] and you're set

Comment: What is an *element*? Integer? Can you go from left to right only once?

Comment: Typical dynamic programming task.

Comment: Will greedy not work? (assuming the ints are positive)

Comment: hop always, then move to the next if the array size is odd?

Comment: @anakata this isn't codegolf. 
fotanus, Calpis what if you've got 1 1 10 1, hopping will make you use the 10.

Comment: Does the solution always include the last array element, or can you terminate on the next-to-last because there's no more data if you hop?

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin for 1,1,10,1 greedy would take the first 1, then compare the next 1 and 10, and take the 1, then compare 10 to the last 1 then take the last 1, so sum would be 3 which is minimal right?

Comment: @Calpis 1,1,10,100,1000 How would your greedy method work in this case? It would take 1,1,10,100,1000. Unless it had branching, but then it's O(2^n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java:

```
static int getMinSum(int elements[])
{
    if (elements == null || elements.length == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No elements");
    }
    if (elements.length == 1)
    {
        return elements[0];
    }
    int minSum[] = new int[elements.length];
    minSum[0] = elements[0];
    minSum[1] = elements[0] + elements[1];
    for (int i = 2; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        minSum[i] = Math.min(minSum[i - 1] + elements[i], minSum[i - 2] + elements[i]);
    }
    return Math.min(minSum[elements.length - 2], minSum[elements.length - 1]);
}
```

Input:

```
int elements[] = { 1, -2, 3 };
System.out.println(getMinSum(elements));
```

Output:

```
-1
```

Case description:

We start from the index 0. We must take 1. Now we can go to index 1 or 2. Since -2 is attractive, we choose it. Now we can go to index 2 or hop it. Better hop and our sum is minimal 1 + (-2) = -1.

Another examples (pseudocode):

```
getMinSum({1, 1, 10, 1}) == 3
getMinSum({1, 1, 10, 100, 1000}) == 102
```

Algorithm:

O(n) complexity. Dynamic programming. We go from left to right filling up minSum array. Invariant: `minSum[i] = min(minSum[i - 1] + elements[i] /* move by 1 */ , minSum[i - 2] + elements[i] /* hop */ )`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you only move from left to right, and you want to find a way to get from index `0` to index `n - 1` of an array of `n` elements, so that the sum of the path you take is minimum. From index `i`, you can only move ahead to index `i + 1` or index `i + 2`.

Observe that the minimum path to get from index `0` to index `k` is the minimum between the minimum path to get from index `0` to index `k - 1` and the mininum path from index `0` to index `k- 2`. There is simply no other path to take.

Therefore, we can have a dynamic programming solution:

```
DP[0] = A[0]
DP[1] = A[0] + A[1]
DP[k] = min(DP[0], DP[1]) + A[k]
```

`A` is the array of elements.
`DP` array will store the minimum sum to reach element at index `i` from index `0`.

The result will be in `DP[n - 1]`.

Comment: The result can be in DP[n - 2]. For example {1, 2, 3} gives DP = {1, 3, 4}. The result is min(DP[n - 2], DP[n - 1]) = 3.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk: Please read the assumption. The question is not too clear on this, so I make the assumption and solve it. It can be relaxed, though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the perfect place for a dynamic programming solution.

Keeping track of two values, odd/even.
We will take `Even` to mean we used the previous value, and `Odd` to mean we haven't.

```
int Even = 0; int Odd = 0;
int length = arr.length;
```

Start at the back. We can either take the number or not. Therefore:

```
Even = arr[length];  
Odd = 0;`
```

And now we move to the next element with two cases. Either we were even, in which case we have the choice to take the element or skip it. Or we were odd and had to take the element.

```
int current = arr[length - 1]
Even = Min(Even + current, Odd + current);
Odd = Even;
```

We can make a loop out of this and achieve a O(n) solution!